# Python Fabric: executing interactive program such as less on remote?

Tags: python, fabric, less-unix

When I execute something like:

```
run('less <somefile>')
```

Within fabric, it prepends the lines with Out: and interacting with it doesn't work as expected.

If I run it with:

```
run('cat <something>', pty=False)
```

The output isn't prepended with anything and I can actually pipe that into less locally, like:

```
fab less | less
```

However I'm not sure if that's recommended since I feel it may be taxing on the remote resource since cat will continually be piping back through ssh.  Also when I quick less before the whole file is cat'd (it could be over 1GB), I get a broker pipe error.

What would be the recommended way to facilitate this?  Should I just use ssh directly like:

```
ssh <remote host> less <something>
```

Comment: As an update, running local('ssh -t <remote host> less <something>') seems to work very well

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing interactive work on the remote host, then maybe just using SSH is fine. I think fabric is mostly useful when automating actions.